# Manga where the MC was transported into another world where there are card game rules

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Need help in finding a manga about a guy transported into another world where there are card game rules.

Things I remember:

- There were multiple factions and he picked the elf one.
- He can summon units every time it's his "turn".
- The art is black and white.

Can't remember anything else, but feel free to ask for additional info and it might help me remember some.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the MC's life before he was transported into the other world? Or what any of the other factions were? Also, when you say the MC can summon "units", do you mean individual elves, or groups of elves?

Comment: there's no story about the past life of the mc if i remember and the units are individual character cards

Comment: just remembered they use cards to summon

Comment: Probably not [Elf Deck to Senjougurashi](https://myanimelist.net/manga/128957/Elf_Deck_to_Senjougurashi)? The main character is a bullied boy who's reincarnated as an elf girl, which seems like it would be a hard detail to forget.

Comment: oh it's that my bad

Answer (score 3):

As @Laurel said in the comments, [Elf Deck to Senjougurashi](https://myanimelist.net/manga/128957/Elf_Deck_to_Senjougurashi):

> The main character is a bullied boy who's reincarnated as an elf girl, which seems like it would be a hard detail to forget.